# How to filter a file based on datetime?

Tags: python, list, file, datetime

I have a file and I want to append some rows to an empty list if they meet 2 conditions:

1. I only take the rows who have a `country_code` which is also present in `my_countrycodes` AND
2. for each `country_code` I take the MAX date-time if that date-time is < `my_time1`

Please note that the `country_code` of each row is indexed at `[1]` in the file and the datetime of each row is a variable named `date_time4`.

This is my code:

```
my_time = '2020-09-06 16:00:45'
my_time1 =  datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 

my_countrycodes = ['555', '256', '1000']

all_row_times = [] #<--- this is the list where we will append the datetime values of the file
new_list = [] #<--- this is the final list where we will append our results
    
with open(root, 'r') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(out, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in reader:  
        # print(row)
        date_time1 = row[-2] + row[-1] #<--- concatenate date + time
        date_time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time1, '%d-%m-%Y%H:%M:%S') #<--- make a datetime object of the string
        date_time3 = datetime.datetime.strftime(date_time2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #<--- turn the datetime object  back to a string
        date_time4 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time3, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #<--- turn the string object  back to a datetime object
        all_row_times.append(date_time4) #<--- put all the datetime objects into a list.
        
        if any(country_code in row[1] for country_code in my_countrycodes) and date_time4 == max(dt for dt in all_row_times if dt <  my_time1): 
            new_list.append(row) #<-- append the rows with the same country_code in my_countrycodes and the latest time if that time is < my_time1
                
print(new_list)
```

This is how the file looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKPCo.png)

This is the output of `new_list`:

```
[['USA', '555', 'White', 'True', 'NY', '06-09-2020', '10:11:32'], 
['USA', '555', 'White', 'True', 'BS', '06-09-2020', '10:11:32'], 
['EU', '256', 'Blue', 'False', 'BR', '06-09-2020', '11:26:21'], 
['GE', '1000', 'Green', 'True', 'BE', '06-09-2020', '14:51:45'], 
['GE', '1000', 'Green', 'True', 'BE', '06-09-2020', '15:59:45']]
```

As you can see the code extracts the rows with the `country_codes` `555`, `256` and `1000`, it also takes the rows which are smaller then < `my_time1`. So this part works perfect. However, row `1000` has 2 different date-times and I dont understand why it doesnt take just the MAX date-time.

This is the expected output of `new_list`:

```
[['USA', '555', 'White', 'True', 'NY', '06-09-2020', '10:11:32'], 
['USA', '555', 'White', 'True', 'BS', '06-09-2020', '10:11:32'], 
['EU', '256', 'Blue', 'False', 'BR', '06-09-2020', '11:26:21'],  
['GE', '1000', 'Green', 'True', 'BE', '06-09-2020', '15:59:45']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it takes just the MAX date-time but in the for loop, the `14:51:45` comes first. Your code compares this to others and since the other value does not come up yet, it is taken as the max value.

On the next iteration, the other country code comes, and since it's time greater than others, this row also appends. This is what you are missing I guess.

You may try something like this.

```
my_time =  datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-09-06 16:00:45', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
my_countrycodes = ['555', '256', '1000']

country_code_max_date_rel = {}
matched_rows = []
with open(root, 'r') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(out, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in reader:
        date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[-2] + row[-1], '%d-%m-%Y%H:%M:%S')
        if any(country_code in row[1] for country_code in my_countrycodes):
            matched_rows.append(row)
            try:
                if country_code_max_date_rel[str(row[1])] < date_time:
                    raise KeyError
            except KeyError:
                country_code_max_date_rel[str(row[1])] = date_time
```

At this point, you have max value for each country. And also the list of rows.
If you filter again like;

```
new_list = []
for row in matched_rows:
    country_code = row[1]
    date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[-2] + row[-1], '%d-%m-%Y%H:%M:%S')
    if date_time == country_code_max_date_rel[country_code]:
        if date_time < my_time:
            new_list.append(row)
```

The new list:

```
[['USA', '555', 'White', 'True', 'NY', '06-09-2020', '10:11:32'],
 ['USA', '555', 'White', 'True', 'BS', '06-09-2020', '10:11:32'],
 ['EU', '256', 'Blue', 'False', 'BR', '06-09-2020', '11:26:21'],
 ['GE', '1000', 'Green', 'True', 'BE', '06-09-2020', '15:59:45']]
```

This code is not really good but I guess it will help you to update yours.

Comment: Thank you abi. Really great piece of code. You mind if I you tell me in pm what you exactly did?

Comment: Thank you bro I will check it.

Comment: I dont see `my_time` back in your code? What did you do with that? How does your code know that it should only take t he rows who are < then `my_time`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Asuming that you want to have only one instance of `contrycode` in your `new_list` with latests time before `my_tim1` here's an anwer:

Logic in you code is incorrect. Right now you are iterating through all rows from you csv file and applies the same condition before appending new row to `new_list`.

In given case `['GE', '1000', 'Green', 'True', 'BE', '06-09-2020', '15:59:45']` is added because condition 1 is True (1000 is in my_countrycodes), and condition 2 is also True (`'06-09-2020', '15:59:45'` is smaller then `my_time1` and it is the 'biggest' time in `new_list` also).

You could aproach this problem in many different ways but here are some suggestions:

1. Change your solution that:
   Check if `row[1]` is in `str(my_countrycodes)`,
   Check if row time is less than `my_time1`
   Check if row's countrycode is already on the `new_list`,
   if it is not in `new_list` add it,
   if it is in `new_list` check if new date and time match your condition and if yes update date and time column for this row.
2. Filter your file by country codes and then retrieve the max from filtered result per country code

Be carefull what is your key, as you have `countrycode` which repets itself with different parameters. ('NY', 'BS')

Suggestion and comments:

1. For quick access to data you could use dictionaries. Using countrycode as a key would grant you easy access to data and help you quickly check for it's existance and update it's parameters.
2. `any(country_code in row[1] for country_code in my_countrycodes)`
   can be written as: 
   `row[1] in str(my_countrycodes)`
   or you even could create `my_country_code_str = str(my_countrycodes)` before entering
   for loop.
3. I do not know why you are casting back and forth datetime but as you only need last one it's enought to do this:
   `rows_date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[-2] + row[-1], '%d-%m-%Y%H:%M:%S')`
   remember that you can format it as you like with `'%d-%m-%Y%H:%M:%S'`
4. Remember to give meaningfull names to your variables and keep one coding standard to your code (ig. when you use underscore then use it successively)